# Verb for "dial a number then immediately hang up"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, telephone

I don't know about English-speaking countries, but where I'm from there's this act whereby you dial a number then immediately hang up, for the sole purpose of letting whoever you're trying to reach know and call you back, especially when you're running out of money and can't make a full call, because they, not you, will be the one to get charged. What's the verb for that act?

> Just _____ me(?) in case you can't afford a phone charge.

I feel like I could almost use this:

> Just *dial my number* in case you can't afford a phone charge.

although I'm not positive the meaning would be clear to a native speaker.

Comment: This isn’t a thing in the west, so far as I’m aware, and we don’t have a word for it. I’d go for “ring my phone”. But isn’t it effectively free to send a text? Or is that expensive / unworkable where you’re from?

Comment: Not the same, but you can do a _reverse charge call_ (called _calling collect_ in the US & Canada). In this case, the charge is pushed to the call receiver, and there's no reason to hang up.

Comment: @DanBron It may not be a thing now, but it certainly used to be a thing. You'd call collect and say the operator would say "A call is coming from 'Mitch Isatthetrainstation'. WIll you accept the charges?" and the receiver would say "No", but then come pick me up at the train station. But I still can't think of how they used to say this in one or two words, without describing the whole operation.

Comment: "Dial me and hang up".

Comment: @DanBron texts are free where you live? Anyway, it's not so much that people here are so poor, but every once in a while you may find yourself financially wanting, don't have enough cash to refill your account for example. I personally still rely on cash, and I often buy cards with serial numbers to recharge my account.

Comment: You have a mistake in your title. A person would dial or call a number, let it ring and then hang up. It is the other person who picks up a call, not the caller.

Comment: @Lambie good point. What would be a good verb from the caller's point of view then? "Go through with the call"?

Comment: @Lambie you can dial a person? Aren't you supposed to dial a number to them?

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw What's the verb in your own language? What's the literal translation into English?

Comment: I see your issue now. :) You dial a person's number. "Just dial me and hang up. Then, **you call me back**."

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw Yes, texts are free here - or, put more concretely, I pay $X/month for my phone plan, and that covers unlimited texting. But even in the old days when each text carried a cost, it was something like 10 cents or so (domestically - back in those days international usage of your phone was extortionate -- still is, but is better).

Comment: @AndrewLeach There is one monosyllabic verb, and one disyllabic variant, but neither is translatable. This is such a common thing that there is verb dedicated to it. The verb started out meaning something to the effect to of "to chew; to gnaw", and somehow it evolved with a modern telephonic meaning. I'm not an etymologist so I can't really explain how or why it acquired this meaning.

Comment: @DanBron I used to "flash call" (mentioned in an answer below) Mum when I was growing up and I'm an Englishman who's still not yet thirty, so I dunno what to tell you except you've obviously led a more luxurious life than me and the OP! :P

Comment: @Mitch Reminds me of this classic commercial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JxhTnWrKYs

Comment: @elmer007 Yes, that's exactly the kind of thing I'm describing. A trick used since forever (ie maybe the 30's?). But... still no one or two word name for the practice that I've heard. Disclaimer: US Eng, and I never actually did this only heard about it from parents.

Comment: @Mitch surely you just could have just given your name as "Mitch Station", "Mitch Kennedy" for the airport serving NYC, "Mitch McDonald" if you were buying burgers for everyone, etc..  If you were expected, it would be at one of very few likely places

Comment: @Mitch I actually have done this. Likely the last time was the 80s. Early 90s at the very latest.

Comment: I think it would make sense to reverse the direction of the duplicate, mostly since this question has many more answers. Thoughts?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Given that much of the English speaking world has had unlimited calling plans, partially unlimited calling plans (e.g. the "[Fave Five](https://www.tmonews.com/2009/11/t-mobile-says-goodbye-to-myfaves/?amp=1)"), or at least very cheap "minutes" for quite some time, I suspect that most people wouldn't know a term for this — I certainly didn't. However, I was able to find some older terms in an article ([Sweethearting, part 2](https://kottke.org/05/10/sweethearting-part-2), from 2005):

> I received reports of pranking being used all over the world. It’s called one-belling (or pranking) in England, people send “toques” (roughly “touches”) or “sting” each other in Spain, Italians “fare uno squillo” (which Google translates as “to make one blast”), and in Finland it’s called “bombing”.
>
> Update: In South Africa, they call it a “Scotch call”.

### One Bell

> To telephone someone and let the phone ring once before hanging up. Usually done when the onebeller is low on credit.
> "I haven't got much credit, so I'll one bell you when I get there and you can call me back, yeah?"
> — [Urban Dictionary, 2009](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=One%20Bell)

### Scotch call

[Partridge](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ak6cBQAAQBAJ&pg=RA3-PA2004-IA28&dq=%22Scotch%20call%22%20phone%20-duck&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj95pSRo-_5AhXvD1kFHduKAcIQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Scotch%20call%22%20phone%20-duck&f=false) defines "scotch call; scotch ring; scotchie (noun)" as South African. "Scotch call" in quotes is used in this [patent by a South African man](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1632101A1). Unfortunately, it doesn't have great connotations:

> A “Scotch call” implies Scots are stingy, referring to hanging up before the other person has answered the phone
> — [ECAJ Antisemitism Report](https://www.ecaj.org.au/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/ECAJ-Antisemitism-Report-2015.pdf)

### Pranking

As for "pranking" I found a [post on the Everything2 forums](https://everything2.com/title/prank):

> In Australian youth slang, to prank someone means to dial their mobile phone, then hang up before they pick up.
>
> It does not necessarily mean doing so in a malevolent way; rather it is a way to avoid exorbitant mobile charges when a person picks up; since phone companies do not charge if the receiver does not answer.
>
> It is used as a verb, e.g., "I'll prank you when I get to your place and you can come down."

From a [Facebook comment](https://m.facebook.com/InnovativeLanguage/photos/a.10150837776981297.397020.112765016296/10152937567521297/?type=1) on a post mentioning supposedly untranslatable words like "Prozvonit (Czech): To call a mobile phone and let it ring once so that the other person will call back, saving the first caller money."

> 'prank' is used this way: "I've got no credit, so I'll prank you when I've got that information."

Also backed up by [Duckspindle](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/454907/duckspindle) in the comments here on ELU:

> I first came across the term 'pranking' in about 2000. My teenage daughter said she would prank me when she arrived safely. When I asked what she meant, she said that she would let the phone ring then hang up, 'like people do with prank calls'. It was a common method of passing a pre-arranged message when each call was charged for - let the phone ring three times and hang up. The recipient would then do the same. If either party didn't hear the three rings, a voice call was in order. I'm not aware of any name for the practice before 'pranking', and these days there is little need for it.

### Flash [Call]

Through Wiktionary I also found to [flash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flash):

> (transitive) To telephone a person, only allowing the phone to ring once, in order to request a call back.
> *Susan flashed Jessica, and then Jessica called her back, because Susan didn't have enough credit on her phone to make the call.*

(Not to be confused with Wiktionary's definition #5 for flash, which is lewd but also transitive.)

Less ambiguously, *flash call*:

> When we had cell phones it was called “beeping.” Now in the era of smartphones another word serves better. It’s “flashing” or “making a flash call.” I think we even did it with land lines as well back in the day. Children away from home would flash call their parents. Though we didn’t recognise it as a thing then.
>
> To make a flash call is to send a message to someone for free simply by calling them up on your phone. Then you (the caller) hang up before the other person gets round to answering the call. As long as the party you are phoning doesn’t pick up the call then you have at least gained their attention without having to pay for a call. That’s a flash call.
>
> [Africa calling: How to say a lot with a little](https://richardcoyne.com/2019/05/04/africa-calling-how-to-say-a-lot-with-a-little/)

Comment: I first came across the term 'pranking' in about 2000. My teenage daughter said she would prank me when she arrived safely. When I asked what she meant, she said that she would let the phone ring then hang up, 'like people do with prank calls'. It was a common method of passing a pre-arranged message when each call was charged for - let the phone ring three times and hang up. The recipient would then do the same. If either party didn't hear the three rings, a voice call was in order. I'm not aware of any name for the practice before 'pranking', and these days there is little need for it.

Comment: Flash call is what I used to use when I grew up in the extremely primitive 90s and 2000s

Comment: Since the OP is looking for a term that they can use today, it's worth mentioning that using "flash" as a transitive verb is a bad idea. Most people would think of something quite different if they heard that "Susan flashed Jessica"!

Comment: In Japan it is ワン切り, wan-giri, one (ring then) cut. It seems [Europol used the term too](https://www.europol.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/wangiri_final_2.pdf) and in Japan it is usually used negatively.

Comment: In Hebrew it's צִילְתּוּק - Tziltuk, a combination of Tziltzul (ring) and Nituk (hang-up).

Comment: Trying to convey a message by the number of rings before hanging up is not a good idea: the recipient's phone's rings might be at different time-intervals from the caller's phone, or on a different phase.

Comment: In German it's "anklingeln". The closest phrase in English would be "to ring so. up". Sadly the English phrase doesn't seem to carry the same connotation.

Comment: When I hear "flash" in the context of a phone call, I think of a three-way conference call (a "hook flash"). If I flash someone on the phone, I'm dialing them in to a three-way call, not letting their phone ring once. Some landline phones used to have a FLASH button for exactly this purpose, although I haven't seen one or heard this usage in over a decade.

Comment: I advise against using "Scotch call". I do not know the etymology, but I suspect it is using the offensive stereotype of Scottish people as mean and not wanting to pay for the call.

Comment: @AdamChalcraft I'm inclined to agree, though the people I knew who did this with landlines in the 80s and 90s were indeed Scottish - coincidentally. I don't recall a compact term, but it was a way of confirming safe arrival without the cost of a long distance call

Comment: As an Aussie, we definitely used the word “prank” for this. As in “prank me when you get there”.

Answer (score 17):

In India, this is usually called a "missed call". Interestingly, that seems to be term used for [the Wikipedia article for this concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missed_call):

> A **missed call** is a [telephone
> call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_call)
> that is deliberately terminated by the caller before being answered by
> its intended recipient, in order to communicate a pre-agreed message.
> It is a form of [one-bit
> messaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-bit_message).
>
> Missed calls are common in [emerging
> markets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerging_markets) where mobile phones with limited outgoing calls are widely
> used; as the call is not actually completed and connected, it does not
> carry a cost to the caller, hence they can conserve their remaining
> [prepaid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepay_mobile_phone) credit. Specific patterns of consecutive missed calls
> have been developed in some countries to denote specific messages.
> Missed calls are also referred to in some parts of
> Africa as **beeping**, **flashing** in Nigeria, a **flashcall** in Pakistan,
> **miskol** in the Philippines and **ring-cut** in Sri Lanka.
>
> Missed calls are especially prominent in India.

Some Indian banks like [Axis Bank](https://www.axisbank.com/bank-smart/toll-free-axis-dial/toll-free-axis-dial) and [SBI](https://www.bankbazaar.com/savings-account/sbi-quick-missed-call-banking.html) have missed-call based services for checking account balances.

Sometimes it's called just a "miss call" - you'd see people send a message saying the equivalent of "I'll give you a miss call", like in [the 2021 movie titled "Miss Call"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13983280/), or [this political party recruitment campaign](https://www.hindustantimes.com/cities/dehradun-news/free-300-power-units-promise-aap-launches-kejriwal-muft-bijli-guarantee-card-in-uttarakhand-101626519496465.html) which had a phone number that people could use to "register by giving a miss call".

Comment: +1 I can vouch for this from my experience as an Indian. We just say 'give me a missed call, and I'll come down to see you', etc.

Comment: This is a useful addition to Laurel's answer, but, to avoid confusing future visitors to this page, it should be made explicit that in the rest of the English-speaking world, *missed call* refers to **any** call that hasn't been answered, for whatever reason. Incidentally, if  in Indian English *missed call* has this very specific meaning, what term would be used for the calls that go unanswered for other reasons?

Comment: Yeah, I would say "I'll 'missed call' you"... it's clunky, but no one word version has caught on.

Comment: Last time I was in India (My first visit to New Delhi) the driver told me to "miss call" him when I was ready to be picked up.

Comment: @jsw29 those would also be missed calls. We just don't need a separate term for intentionally making a call that isn't supposed to be picked up. In the ordinary course of things, how often would you need to (or even be able to after the fact) distinguish between the two?

Comment: @ReginaldLloyd in the UK I've come across this with mobiles as a way of sharing phone numbers that reduces overall typing, while checking correct entry. A tells B their own number, B missed calls A; they now have each other's numbers

Comment: @muru, the OP does 'need a separate term for intentionally making a call that isn't supposed to be picked up'.

Comment: @jsw29 granted that's what OP wants, but of course the same term can have separate meanings, and the context in which "miss[ed] call" is used is enough to distinguish these senses. And I ask again, since you have dodged it once, can you provide a situation in which these two meanings have to be distinguished? Then I can elaborate on how an Indian might phrase things to make the difference clear.

Comment: Also, I'd like to clarify that this isn't just a term in Indian *English* - the same term transliterated (accounting for differences in phonetics) is used in Hindi, Malayalam, Marathi and Tamil (by personal experience in states in which these languages are dominant). I'd think this would hold for most of the other Indian languages too.

Comment: I do not mean disrespect toward Indian English, but I'd rather not model my English after it. I've heard Indian speakers use amusing expressions such as "can be able", which I'd vehemently object to, because it sounds ridiculously redundant. If you've watched one of those Indian scammers video you've probably also heard of "each and every thing", which in itself is not "wrong", but Indian scammers seem to use it exclusively in place of "everything", rather than just an occasional emphatic expression. All this is a roundabout way of saying I wouldn't rely on "non-standard" English varieties.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw so... what's a *standard* English variety?

Comment: @muru Don't take this the wrong way, but I'd say stick to the varieties used in the UK, the US, Canada and Australia. Anything beyond these is not exactly popular. I'm saying this as a teacher. I'd rather not teach Southeast-Asian-style tag questions or Indian coinages such as "can be able". I don't want to cause any debate over what "standard" means, but I don't want to model my own English on or to teach "non-standard" varieties either. If it's how you speak in India, cool, but it's not my or my students' preferred way.

Comment: @muru For your information, people in my country generally don't think of anyone born outside the aforementioned countries as a "native speaker". When they go to English-language schools, expecting to learn the "native way" from "native teachers", Indians aren't the first people coming into mind. It's cool to know that there's a word in Indian English for what I'm looking for, but I myself am not a native speaker, I might have to use it or teach it to my students one day, and I need to know what the "correct" or "native" way to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138944/discussion-between-vun-hugh-vaw-and-muru).

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw for your example, Indians would likely say "Just *miss-call* me in case you can't afford a phone charge" or "Just *give me a missed call* in case you can't afford a phone charge".

Answer (score 13):

When I was younger (UK-based): **give me two rings**

Whilst not a single verb, back in the day, this was a common request when a paid call was not called for - e.g. "give me two rings to let me know you got back ok". The expectation being that you'd dial the number, let it ring twice, then hang up without connecting the call.

Another use of "two rings" was as a pre-arranged request to be called back. Once the '1471' service was introduced (to find the number that had just called you), and/or newer phones started to have caller ID available, this could include when you wouldn't know in advance the number of the phone you would be calling from (e.g. payphones or similar), or cases where several different people might be expecting a call back.

Probably not in common usage any more, considering how phones have changed (besides anything else, counting the rings doesn't make sense when most phones play melodies now!), but likely recognised at least by those who used the term back in the day.

Comment: Common phrase (or similar “let it ring once”) in the States, also.

Comment: Even before 1471 two rings at an expected time were used like this. I have a vague recollection of a more complicated system too - one ring, hang up, redial immediately allowing some small number of rings

Comment: We must have been rich, coz we always used _three_ rings… As you say, I mainly recall it being used to let e.g. grandparents know that we'd reached home safely. (I suspect that, even 30 years ago, the rings you heard over the phone line didn't necessarily correspond with those the recipient would have heard, so maybe 3 gives more of a safety margin?)

Comment: @gidds in analogue phone systems, the rings did correspond very well between caller and receiver. It's a while since I tested with a modern phone

Comment: @ChrisH 1. I tweaked the paragraph mentioning '1471' to get the better emphasis.
2. I recall even quite some time ago being a bit surprised when a calling and called phone analogue were in earshot of each other that the rings did NOT directly correspond, at least on my local telephone exchange. It would alternate between ringing the phone and playing a "phone ringing" noise to the caller. Leaving it at least two sets of rings would thus ensure it actually had a chance to sound at the other end.

Comment: @Steve that's the case now, certainly. If I've got a dumb phone plugged in at the same time as my cordless land-line, they're not even in sync with each other (the cordless plays a ringtone that sounds like a phone ringing when it recurve receives the signal that directly drives the sounder on the old imparted unpowered handset). 2 sets would only just be enough calling from my mobile to my cordless land-line.

Answer (score 11):

Although the word is not restricted to phone calls, one possibility is **ping**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ping)
> *ping*
> to send a usually brief message (such as a text message) or notification to (a person, a person's phone, etc.)
> *… provides an opportunity to check the time or see who pinged you while you were coming down the mountain …*

The ringing of the phone is thus a notification without verbal exchange and fits within the M-W definition.

Similarly, we have “other kind of message” in:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ping)
> *ping*
> to send an email, text, or other kind of message, especially to someone's mobile phone

Hence, we may say *”Just ping me so I know to call you back”*

Comment: No, pinging is texting or messaging, not for dialing a phone number. No, we would say: Just call me and hang up before I pick up.

Comment: @Lambie You might well think so (as did I at first) but have you considered the dictionary definitions I offer? I did. And so it is that "other kind of message" and "notification" go beyond a text, a message or a simple phone call. Computers "ping" each other without text or message. My broadband speed checker "pings" a distant computer to measure speed. We have to move with the times.

Comment: @Lambie no, pinging is submarines using sonar to locate each other. No wait, it's only a command used to measure lag and packet loss on networks. No actually, it's exclusively a miniature version of tennis played on a table top.

Comment: Native english-speaker here. If someone said they were going to "ping" me when they got home, I wouldn't assume they'd specifically call and hang up like this, but I would recognise this was what they meant after the fact. Generally it just means "I'll send you some sort of indication that I'm home safe". With the expectation that there's no conversation attached, just a "I'm home safe", " :) " text-chat or something.

Comment: @candied_orange Oh wait, a person can't be expected to cite every single usage.

Comment: @Lambie the point was to refute the idea that one can refute a usage claim by citing other usages. Words don't work that way. They aren't loyal. They sneak around and live independent lives.

Comment: @candied_orange "refute the idea one can refute a usage claim by citing other usages". That is the only way to do it. I know of no other way. Some words have multiple meanings but we don't say ping a cell or mobile phone. And now, we see that **in India** they say: miss call me. Very clever.

Comment: @Lambie knowing no other way is not evidence of there being no other way.

Comment: This is what we used to call it (90s, UK). But I'm not sure it would be widely understood now.

Comment: @Lambie I'd certainly consider "ping" valid for dialling a phone number

Comment: @candied_orange I responded to you and now you are basically trolling.

Comment: @candied_orange For someone who is knowledgeable, knowing no other way is no guarantee but it is a good indication of there being no other way or that the other way is less likely or obscure.

Comment: Weird coincidence that the previous stackexchange question I read just before this one was [Does absence of evidence mean evidence of absence?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92546/does-absence-of-evidence-mean-evidence-of-absence)

Comment: @Lambie The point of these comments is supposed to be to improve Antons answer. Simply arguing that ping has other usages doesn't help Antons answer. If Anton claimed the sky is blue it would be silly to dispute that by saying, "no, violets are blue". A better argument would be the sky isn't blue at night. Because at least that's relevant to the sky.

Answer (score 11):

It's probably not a popular answer.  I think it deserves to be its own answer:

No.  There is no phrase that you could use(at least in the USA).

The best you could say is  "I rang once and hung up.  Call me back so I don't have to pay my minute rate."  If you said "I pinged you." It would leave too much room for interpretation and not be considered good communication unless you had previously stated your intent.  Most would see a ring/hangup as an accidental dial.

I remember that ringing and hanging up was very briefly a "thing" in the late 90's when minute rates were sometimes tied to the caller but not the receiver.  This was when cellphones were just coming out and this business model didn't seem to last more than a couple years.  So no, Americans never made a phrase for it.

Comment: I agree with the gist of your answer, but I was taught this technique for payphones by my parents if us kids went at saw a movie (early 2000s before cell phones). They'd expect a phone call around 2 hours after show time and wouldn't answer. If we hung up after 3 rings, they'd come grab us from the theater and we'd get our quarters back from the payphone. Since they taught it to us, it was probably something they did growing up with payphones too.

Comment: Robin is right.  There were also "collect" calls that one could decline without either party paying money.  You would get a call from a collect call operator who would state "You have a call from Robin Clower, would you like to accept".  Payphones were classic examples of charging the caller instead of the receiver.

Comment: +1 since (with all due respect to the many thoughtful answers given thus far) the OP will never find an expression with this meaning that even a tenth of North Americans can understand. Frankly, even spelling it out as "Call me and then immediately hang up" will probably have 70% of us wondering "Why on Earth would I do that?"

Answer (score 6):

### A Drop Call.

In London, UK we'd refer to this as a "drop call", usually in the context of confirming/sharing a telephone number.

However, I would do this as a teenager on Pay As You Go credit to call my parents to prompt them to call back to use their contracted minutes.

e.g.

> "Drop call me when you're ready to get picked up and I'll call you back to arrange where to meet."

Referenced on https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drop%20call

Comment: That seems to postdate my time in London (up to the mid 90s) so may have become common when mobile phones did.

Comment: @ChrisH Yeah, it was late 90s-early 00s and it was almost exclusively about mobile phone calls.

Comment: A few rich friends had them by '97, but even they would use tricks to reduce the cost of calling

Comment: Same, it was when I was moving onto college from secondary school and the kids started inheriting their parents' nokias. Don't blame them for saving money, at 10p per text. That's a Freddo!

Answer (score 6):

A term used locally in South Africa is "miss(ed) call", referring to the notification you will receive, typically on a mobile phone:

> Missed call received from $contact info or number$

This is used as a noun:

> "Give me a missed call when you arrive, then I'll call you back."

or less commonly as a verb:

> "Miss call me when you arrive, then I'll call you back"

Source: I live in SA

Side note: prepaid call plans are common here. In order to initiate a call to generate a missed call, there needs to be credit on the call plan. If you are completely out of credit, the only option is to send a "Please call me": a free text message which is sent when you use a certain USSD code.

Comment: +1 I can vouch for this from my experience as an Indian. We just say 'give me a missed call, and I'll come down to see you', etc. Also answered by muru.

Answer (score 4):

Earlier generations in England referred to this as a "Scotch call".
This is an impolite reference to saving money.

Comment: This is great for historical record, but, to be clear, would be inappropriate to use nowadays.

Comment: @Mitch I never heard it in England but it sounds a reasonable regional suggestion. Certainly it is offensive now.

Comment: Is it impolite to the Scotch people or to the caller?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The offense lies in using 'Scotch' as a synonym for cheap/stingy/miserly (thereby perpetuating a negative stereotype)... If the phrase were something like "miser's call" then that would not be deemed offensive.

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero So it's impolite to the Scots.

Comment: @Mitch it wouldn't be "inappropriate" at all... who decides? the government?! lol... I'm scotch and I don't care. in fact "Scotching" would be a good catchy word for it.

Comment: @ReginaldLloyd Depends on the social context (governments sometimes influence that). So for your context, no. But in the current US context, making any connection between a group and a negative term associated with that group is considered inappropriate.

Comment: @ReginaldLloyd [I thought people from Scotland bristle at the label 'Scotch'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_(adjective)#:~:text=Scotch%20is%20an%20adjective%20in,Scotch%20pie%20and%20Scotch%20broth.) (for the people). Is that not the case in general, or were you just telling us your own personal feelings about the terms directed at yourself?

Comment: @Mitch, it's recent radical ideologue rubbish like that trying to control language and be offended on behalf of other people over traditional and normal expressions that is inappropriate. Why can't you accept that you are just wrong? It's not "inappropriate", and it's not about the feelings of anyone who corrects you, you're just wrong, end of. There is no "US context" about it. "Scotch" is whisky, tape, food items, adjectives and verbs... no Orwellian attempt to censor words like this is going to work. At best, Scots don't use the word "Scotch" very often, except in jest or in names of things

Comment: @ReginaldLloyd Can you elaborate on "'Scotch' is not used very much"? That would give much needed nuance to this answer. How can it be used in jest?

Comment: phrases like "Scotch mist", or like with any word... like Paddy, or Monkeyhanger (people from Hartlepool), the word "black" is a neutral word by itself, but if said in a variety of tones, or situations it can take on all kinds of nuances. A recent case of a historical pub in Scotland with a very old name it's had for years being changed because people from outsiders who don't understand or care about the history or etymology of the term - they just imposing their own foreign meaning: https://mylinlithgow.com/directory/listing/all-businesses/the-black-bitch/ this is why etymology is important

Comment: @ReginaldLloyd These are all legitimate points you're making about how these words feel to people saying and hearing them, but it seems more of the 'socio' part of sociolinguistics than the 'ling' part. History of the meaning of a word sure does give a hint to the current meaning but there's no guarantee that word will stay the same. If 'Scotch' used to be exactly the demonym, but 'Scots' is used more frequently nowadays rendering 'Scotch' old-fashioned, maybe that is contributing to the humor you find yourself in the word, but also to the denigration others feel (and want to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

Not a word but more of a phrase.

My friends and I call it "phone bombing" eg. "Just phone bomb me when you get home".

I'm in Australia and pranking works too.
I just asked my son and he said "oh a spam call"

Comment: Is this used by anyone other than you and your friends?

Answer (score 0):

**Page** describes the general action of asynchronously requesting that another person initiate a synchronous discussion with them. In other words, doing something that communicates the message "please call me back" is a *page*. It doesn't necessarily mean this is accomplished by making a phone call and then hanging up, but if both parties understand the meaning of that action, it would be considered a page / paging someone.

Comment: This word is certainly used for a similar action with phones but is very much distinct since this is for a request to speak and the OP is looking for something where no one speaks at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the UK it's common to hear people say "Just missed-call me" - It's a bit awkward and doesn't count as one word if that's important, but people know exactly what you mean.

It's commonly used when you want to give someone your phone number.
They tell you their number, you missed-call them, then after your "missed call" has come up on their phone they can select your number from it to "Add as a new contact".

This usage has been around for years. Here is a discussion from 2013: https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst46104_Give-me-a-missed-call.aspx

I have read online that in the US people sometimes say "Just buzz me" - which counts as a single word verb, but to me "buzz me" would mean "call/phone me" like we'd say "ring me" and wouldn't in any way say that the call is not to be answered.

I have never heard "buzz" used to specifically mean a missed call. Likewise, if someone said "ping me" - that could count as a text or a call, it just means to make contact. It doesn't specifically mean a missed call.

Answer (score 0):

### Beep

Before phones, we used to have "pagers" or "beepers". In particular, hospital personnel used to have those. Some beepers could receive short text or voice messages, but some beepers just produced a "beep" sound when they were called, with no message other than the one beep.

Using a phone just to send one ring is emulating a beeper. You can use the transitive word "beep" for this meaning.

This definition is listed in [WordReference Random House Unabridged Dictionary of American English © 2022](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/beep):

> **beep** (v.t.)
>
> to announce, warn, summon, etc., by beeping:
>
> *The doctor was beeped to call the hospital.*